# eigenvalues by matrix factorisation, e.g. QR

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

What are the origins/motivation behind that idea?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to take a look at Watkins' book "The Matrix Eigenvalue Problem - GR and Krylov subspace methods". It is very well written and will give you insight on the working of the QR method. I think there are some historical remarks as well.

Answer (score 0):

The book by Trefethen and Bau is very readable.